# Every two maps are chain homotopic

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I have to show the following thing:

1. Every two maps $ \varphi, \psi: \Delta_{\star}(X\times Y) \to \Delta_{\star}(X) \otimes \Delta_{\star}(Y)$  are chain homotopic (which are trivial on degree 0).
2. Every two maps $\varphi,\psi: \Delta_{\star}(X\times Y) \to \Delta_{\star}(X) \otimes \Delta_{\star}(Y)$ are chain homotopic (which are trivial on degree 0).

I think I know how to do it but at the end I miss one calculation:
In both cases I define inductvly a chain homotopy. In 0 degree everything is clear. For the induction step I define $D$ on a model in the first case on $d_n: \Delta_n \times \Delta_n \to \Delta_n$ beeing the diagonal embedding and in the second case on $i_p: \Delta_p \to \Delta_p$ beeing the identity. Then have to define (by naturality of $D$) the general maps that way:

1. $D\sigma =  (\pi_X\sigma)_\Delta \otimes (\pi_Y\sigma)_\Delta (Dd_n)$
2. $D(\sigma \otimes \tau) = <\sigma,\tau>_\Delta (D(i_p \otimes i_q))$

But now I still need to show that $D\delta +\delta D = \varphi- \psi$ in general. (I know this by construction for the models).

How can I do that?